# BIRT transpose results table

Tags: javascript, mysql, birt, transpose

I'm using a BIRT report with rather complicated query to get different metrics from multiple tables.
Those metrics are done for data between two dates set as parameter and with different periodicity.
So I don't know how many rows will be in the output.

In the end I get table like this:

```
           Metric A | Metric B | Metric C
2017/01       1          0         4
2017/02       0          3         4
2017/03       1          2         3
```

In the report design, I need to display it as transposed (metric names are long and there is too many of them).

How can I do it within the report itself? 
I think this is more difficult to be done in the query (I don't know how many rows I get in the result - it is dynamically taken from the dates and according to the periodicity).

I tried so far:

- Cubes and crosstables - but how can I do it, when I don't know how many columns I get in the end?
- Scripting - I can dynamically add more columns or create the table as it is. But how do I get the data from dataset? Here I tried to do something like this:

Firstly, in the dataset onFetch method, I put something in the report variable:

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("metric_1",row["metric_1"].toString());
```

Then, in the report beforeFactory, I try to access the variable:

```
mylabel.setText( reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("metric_1") );
```

But the result is empty.

Is this a wrong way to do it? Do you have any ideas? I would like to do it in the script - set report data to the globalVariable, then in the beforeFactory access the resultSet and create table for it.

Do you have any other ideas?

P.S. it is very unfortunate that you can't have something like detailColumn (you do have detailRow).